How to redirect to particular screen using deeplink in Flutter?
I want to open the particular screen of my app when I click on the email link. I have given the scheme and host in the android manifest file like below.
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="aaaa.com" />
                <data android:scheme="aaaa" />
            </intent-filter>

So when I click on the link, it is redirecting to my app. But it is not opening the specific screen which I want. I have tried the below code. But it keeps opening the screen which is already open.
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: const Color.fromRGBO(26, 49, 60, 1),
        ),
      ),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        name: 'email_screen',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialPage(child: EmailScreen(

          ));
        }
    ),
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        name: 'reset_screen',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialPage(child: ResetScreen(

          ));
        }
    ),
  ],

);

I want to open the reset_screen. But it is not working. I am new to flutter. Please someone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

I am using a package named app_links. But there are many others.
The packages have 2 ways to get the link:

initial link
link stream

Handle the initial link anywhere you are sure it is only called once.
Then add a listener to the stream.
The receiver of the link should have excess to BuildContext e.g. from a statefull widget. But be sure the context of the receiver is always mounted (in the widgettree).
Then you have to handle the link as you need based of its content and use e.g. Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...).
